# How do I prevent the instructions after setInterval() from being executed before the interval is cleared?

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval

I am using a `for` loop where I'm updating an *svg*. I want a delay after each loop so that an animation is created. I tried putting the code in the for loop inside a `setInterval` function so that the animation effect is created. But the function is not getting executed though the syntax is perfect :

```
setInterval(func, 80);
```

Instead, the instructions coming after the `setInterval` are executed. In debug mode, if I debug the code and keep running for a long time, after a while the required loop is entered.

So, I thought maybe the delay is too long and tried reducing the delay but it is not working then too. 
I've tried all kinds of versions of the `setInterval` syntax i.e. with parenthesis and without and by reference and by copy too but it's just not happening!

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant parts of your actual code? A single `setInterval` line really isn't helpful.

Comment: You have to provide a little bit more of code here, as is, this would execute the function `func` every 80 milliseconds, which isn't helping much here.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `setInterval` does. It's not the same as "sleep()" function in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop you can use the following to loop you code with a 100 milliseconds wait each time

```
function UpdateSVG()
{
  // ... your code here

  setTimeout(UpdateSVG, 100);
}

UpdateSVG();
```